# Model not being saved using Selenium but saved using Rack::Test

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara, activeadmin

I have the following test that works in Rack::Test but not using Selenium. I.e. if I add `, js: true` to the describe block, I get an error message in Firefox saying that it `couldn't find the License with id=`(the id of `@l`)

```
describe "should hide allocation rule # for pdf & clickthrough licenses" do

  it "reads current state and shows/hides fields appropriately" do                                     
    @l = FactoryGirl.create(:license:,
                          way: License::CLICK_WAY)                                                                                      
    visit edit_admin_license_path(@l)                                                                                           
  end
end
```

**Why?** I must be missing *something*. I can verify with Sequel Pro that the record is not getting saved when using `js: true`.

I need this spec to run in Selenium because I have javascript to test.

Comment: Try checking `log/test.log` and verify that the correct actions are being reached. You could also add `save_and_open_page` after `visit` to show the page in a browser.

Comment: Might have something to do with your database strategy, could you include `spec_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to turn transactional fixtures off.

[Why does my Cucumber test fail when run with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524500/why-does-my-cucumber-test-fail-when-run-with-selenium)

in spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before :each do
    if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

and in the Gemfile, test section

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

Comment: Here's a good ref on setting up your config for rspec request specs: http://highgroove.com/articles/2012/04/06/sane-rspec-config-for-clean,-and-slightly-faster,-specs.html

Comment: Thanks shioyama, great article!