# RSpec, Capybara, JavaScript Tests Not Properly Rolling back the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

So, I am testing my Ruby on Rails project, but I am having a problem with the database.

I am using Stripe, and I am running integration tests for each of the pages along the user's purchasing experience.  After a run through of the tests, my database is not rolling back, though!

It's very frustrating, because after each test I need to run `rake db:test:prepare`, and that is slowing me down.

Below is the code for my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Subscription Pages" do
  subject { page }

  ...


  describe "purchase page" do

  ...

  describe "when not signed in" do
    it { should have_field "Email" }
    it { should have_field "Full Name" }
    it { should have_field "Password" }
    it { should have_field "Confirmation" }

    describe "and fills in the provided sign-up form as new user" do
      let(:some_user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Full Name",             with: some_user.name
        fill_in "Email",                 with: some_user.email
        fill_in "Password",              with: some_user.password
        fill_in "Confirmation",          with: some_user.password
        fill_in "card_number",           with: "4242424242424242"
        fill_in "card_code",             with: "123"
        select "January", from: "card_month"
        select (Date.today.year+1).to_s, from: "card_year"
      end

      ...

      describe "and submits with valid information", js: true do
        before do
          click_button submit
          sleep 5
        end

        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Thank you for purchasing!') }
        it { should have_field "Words" } # because its the new puzzle page.
        it { should_not have_link "Buy Now!", href: plans_path }

        describe "and then tries to revisit the purchase page", js: true do
          before do
            visit purchase_path
          end

          # Should redirect to account screen with an alert
          # These tests pass when I do them myself but don't know why they are failing here
          specify { User.find_by_email(some_user.email).subscription.paid_user?.should be_true }

          it { should have_selector( 'title', text: "Account") }
          it { should_not have_field "card_number" }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-notify') }
          it { should_not have_link "Buy Now!", href: plans_path }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

If I start by running `rake db:test:prepare` and then run my tests, everything is great.  However, when I go to run the tests again, I get "Email already taken" validation errors on my User model since the database was not rolled back.

What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: which capybara driver are you using ?

Comment: I believe its Selenium - but how can I check for sure?  I don't know 100% and not sure where to check...

Comment: Capybara.current_session.driver (inside a spec) will tell you what the current driver is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that while :rack_test is the default driver used by Capybara for regular tests, javascript tests are executed using a different driver (:selenium), which [does not support transactional fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524500/why-does-my-cucumber-test-fail-when-run-with-selenium) ([without some workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium)).

If that does not resolve the problem, nesting of javascript blocks within non-javascript blocks (especially interactive steps like visit/click/fill) can have erratic results in my experience, so I would avoid doing that.

As an aside, sleep is not a good idea and you might want to consider `wait_until` and `wait_for_ajax`.

Comment: Awesome Prusswan.  Will have to look into those two links and will accept the answer if they work. (Will probably do that sometime tomorrow or next day...)

Regarding `wait_until` and `wait_for_ajax`, I couldn't get them to work, and I had a deadline to meet, and sleep did the job.  I plan on refactoring that now that the deadline has passed...

Comment: To be clear, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774227/why-not-use-shared-activerecord-connections-for-rspec-selenium) is what I tried.  Took 2 seconds and everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

in hour `spec/rspec_helper.rb`

Also, not sure what code you omitted in your example, but anything you are creating in `before(:all)` you need to clean up yourself in `after(:all)`, cause this is invoked before a transaction is opened.

Comment: I don't have any `before(:all)` or `after(:all)`, and

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

is set in `spec/spec_helper.rb` 

Any other ideas?